# what if external storage is unavailable?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My app needs to write data into files (should be user-accessible).
Now I usually check whether external storage is available/writable or not.
If it's available & writable, app would be able to save data to external storage.
It at all, the external storage is not available, what should be my next option to write/store data that user can access easily. (writing data into internal storage might be frustrating for the user to search).
help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the external storage is unavailable and you want the data to be user accessible, then you should show a dialog informing the user that he/she should make the external storage accessible (putting in an SD Card or disconnecting from the computer, whatever is required). For small files, you could maybe try asking the user and uploading them to his/her dropbox or Google Drive or some other cloud storage accounts.

Also, keep in mind, that as Budius said in the comments, all devices wil have an external storage, even if it isn't available at the moment. This is not completely true though. All device which have been verified by Google and have Google Play will have an external storage. Devices running custom hardware and modified versions of Android may not.

Comment: Again, thanks Raghav !!
my question was, what if a device does not have/support external storage (As not all devices do that). and I still want my app to write/save data locally and make it user-accessible

Comment: Then the cloud would be your best option. Or you could save it to the internal storage, and allow the user to access it through your app, and for other apps to access it through content providers.

Comment: Writing it to the internal storage and letting the users access through the app seems to be the only option for me !!
By the way, is there any case where internal storage could be full ??

Comment: @user1698550 Yes, it is very likely that it will be full. Most devices hand only a few hundred MB of internal storage, which is to be shared by lots of apps. It is also where apps are installed to, so that takes up additional space

Comment: ps.: every device does have a externalStorage, it might not be available at the moment, but it does exist. Some devices implement is as flash memory (nexus) and some implement it as SD-card (might not be available)

Comment: thanks for the concern guys. 
now, after writing the data to internal storage and what if I want to save the data even after user uninstalling the app ?
is that possible to stop android from removing all the app data in internal storage ?

Comment: That's not possible I'm afraid. The data in internal storage is written to your app directory, which is deleted when the user uninstalls the app.